# Azure policy to require a certain Tag be created, but not with a default value?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to create an Azure policy that requires a Tag exist on a resource when it's created, but not check for a specific value? All the examples I've seen are for "check if tag X is there, and has value Y".

I want to simply let the user know "you need to put tag X on this resource" because the value is user-defined so I can't enforce a specific value.

For example - I need "BillingCode" on every resource, but only the person creating the resource knows their correct billing code since it's different for each person or project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subscription policies to accomplish this. They will prevent deployment of Azure resources unless certain rules are met.

Below example taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-on-resource-groups).
You could modify this example by using the `notMatch` operator instead of the direct match below. [More operators here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-rule).

```
{
   "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value on resource groups",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value on resource groups.",
      "mode": "All",
      "parameters": {
         "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
            }
         },
         "tagValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as headquarter"
            }
         }
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
            "allOf": [
               {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
               },
               {
                  "not": {
                     "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                     "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`exists` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#conditions).

For example:

```
{
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to require `tagValue` as well, without specifying any default value?

Comment: @stack247 Use equals, e.g.
`                            {
                                "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                                "equals": ""
                            }

Comment: thanks. I tried your approach with `tagValue` (instead of `tagName`) but when creating resource group in Azure portal, it doesn't honor the rule.. technically, the `tagValue` is `""`, so the validation pass.

Comment: @stack247 Ask this as a separate question so that you can include your entire policy rule. I suspect you just need to flip a condition somewhere (add `not`). If it's only not working for resource groups, keep in mind that you need to use `"mode": "all"` for a policy to apply to resource groups.